# looking for solution solution to make my dropdown menu unique by each element selected wthin my table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**I want, when clicking on the three-dot menu, it appears only one menu, but I'm getting all the menus after mapping my array. The first picture is my result, and the second picture is the result I'm looking for.**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC9tY.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC9tY.png
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J52ep.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/J52ep.png

Here's my code:

```js
{ClientsData.map((u, index) => (
    <tr id={`element-${index}`} className={u.checked ? 'user active' : 'user'} key={u.id}>
        <td className="input-check">
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>{u.email}</td>
        <td>{u.societe}</td>
        <td>{u.matriculeFiscale}</td>
        <td>{u.categorie}</td>
        <td>{u.reglement}</td>
        <td className={u.statut === 'Bloqué' ? 'user-status' : 'user-status activé'}>
            {u.statut}
        </td>
        <td className="last-user-element">
            <Link to={`/admin/users/user_details/${u.id}`} className="link-user">
                <icons.BsEye className="see-user" />
            </Link>
            <div className="contain">
                <icons.BsThreeDotsVertical
                    onClick={() => {
                        setOpenDropdown(!openDropdown);
                        setIndice(u.id);
                        setIndexUser(index);
                    }}
                    className="user-option"
                    key={u.id}
                />
                {openDropdown && <UsersModalOptions />}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Comment: You're going to want to not only save whether or not the dropdown is open but also for which user the dropdown is open (I assume you do this by calling `setIndice(u.id);`).

After you have the user id for whom the dropdown should be open you should tweak your condition from

`{openDropdown && <UsersModalOptions />}`

to something along the lines of

`{(openDropdown && currentIndice == u.id) && <UsersModalOptions />}`

Comment: you could also split the dropdown into its own component, so the drop down state isn't shared by all the rows